# Javascript replace double quotes with slash

Tags: javascript

I want to replace `"`  with `\"` with Javascript.

I have:

```
text = text.toString().replace("\"", '\\"')
```

The result:

```
\\"
```

Comment: did u try removing one of the back slashes?

Answer (score 53):

Try this:

```
text = text.toString().replace(/"/g, '\\"')
```

Or this:

```
text = text.toString().replace('"', '\\"')
```

Comment: Watch out! Second example replaces only first occurance of double quote in a string. Only the regex overload replaces all.

Answer (score 6):

I have a small suggestion based on antyrat's answer.

```
text = text.toString().replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

This extra step will replace all the \" to " first, and then replace all the " back to \". It will help when your current string contains a combination of \" and ", especially when the string is a result from JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
text = text.toString().replace("\"", '\\\"');
```

You basically have to escape both '\' and '"' by \

Answer (score 1):

var text = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(text))